# Is arithmetic a context free grammar?

Tags: context-free, arithmetic

Like including parenthesis (`(` and `)`), addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, and the Order of Operations in mind.

I tried (in [Lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark) EBNF):

```
%import common.WS
%ignore WS
%import common.SIGNED_NUMBER -> NUMBER

start: exp
?exp : add
     | mul
     | sub
     | div
     | NUMBER
     | frac
     | parenthesis
?parenthesis: "(" exp ")"
add  : exp "+" exp
sub  : exp "-" exp
mul  : (exp "*" exp) | NUMBER parenthesis
div  : exp "/" exp
```

I wonder if the Order of Operations would make arithmetic a context-free grammar.

*<sub>Originally [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141999/is-arithmetic-a-context-free-grammar)</sub>*

Comment: Let's start with a more basic question. *Is arithmetic a grammar?*

Comment: Please show your attempts.  What are your thoughts?  How would you approach it?  Can you solve any simplified version of this problem, e.g., with only addition and multiplication, or only addition?

Comment: There is a big confusion here between *languages*, *grammars that describe them*, and *grammars that allow their correct parsing*.

Comment: The grammar is ambiguous. I'd say that is a major, major problem. What is 10 - 5 - 2 ?

Comment: @gnasher729 ambiguous as a grammar or as a grammar? See [Yuval Filmus' comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/130675/#comment274209_130675).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two or three different concepts here:

- Languages: these are collections of strings.
- Context-free grammars: this is a specific way to describe languages.
- Parsing: this is the process in which a computer "understands" input.

You haven't explained what you mean by "arithmetic"; some people think of arithmetic as the set of first-order statements about the natural numbers which are true, for example. However, it seems that by arithmetic you mean the set of well-formed arithmetic expressions (you leave out some important details, for example, what atoms are allowed, whether whitespace is allowed, and so on). Assuming this, arithmetic is most certainly *not* a context-free grammar, simply because arithmetic is a *language*, not a *grammar*. However, it can be described as a context-free grammar, as you demonstrate.

The next thing you are worried about is parsing ("order of operations"). Grammars describe languages, that is, sets of strings; parsing is a separate issue. It is true that context-free grammars are intimately related to parsing, via parse trees. It is possible to construct a context-free grammar for the language of arithmetic expressions that reflects "order of operations", in the sense that we can use the parse tree directly to evaluate the expressions in a recursive way (in the fashion of [attribute grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_grammar).

For example, suppose that the only atom is $n$, and that we are only interested in addition and multiplication, and allow parentheses; and furthermore, multiplication has higher priority than addition, and both associate to the left. This is reflected in the following grammar:

\begin{align}
&\mathit{EXPR} \to \mathit{EXPR} + \mathit{TERM} \mid \mathit{TERM} \\
&\mathit{TERM} \to \mathit{TERM} * \mathit{FACTOR} \mid \mathit{FACTOR} \\
&\mathit{FACTOR} \to (\mathit{EXPR}) \mid n
\end{align}

You can check that $n+n+n$ is "understood" as $[n+n]+n$, and $a+b*c$ is understood as $a+[b*c]$, for example. Moreover, this grammar is unambiguous (unless I made a mistake), that is, any word in the language has a unique parse tree.

In practice, starting with an ambiguous context-free grammar and precedence rules (including associativity), parser generators can create equivalent unambiguous context-free grammars (or more accurately, parsing algorithms).

Comment: "Definition" of `Languages` needs rewording. Not every `"collection of strings"` can be called a `language`.

Comment: Here is the standard definition: a language over $\Sigma$ is a subset of $\Sigma^*$.